# First letter of each word in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `borrower` with a column named `given_names`.

I want a SQL query to display all the initials of the `given_names` column
Meaning every first letter of a word in the `given_names` column

I tried:

```
select substring(cast (given_names as text),1,1) + substring(given_names,charindex('')+(' ',given_names)+1,1) 
from borrower
```

Comment: select substring(cast (given_names as text),1,1) + substring(given_names,charindex('')+(' ',given_names)+1,1) from borrower

Comment: Using split_to_table or regexp_split_to_table may be a benefit here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74881/postgresql-get-first-letter-of-each-word-except

Comment: That functionality is string specific, i have tried doing it for the whole column but do not get a successful query as per my attempt mentioned on top

Comment: You query has several errors: First: the [string concatenation operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) in SQL is `||`, not `+`. Secondly: there is no `charindex()` function in Postgres (all string functions can be found [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)). And the `cast(... as text)` is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, `regexp_split_to_table` will help out a lot here.

The idea is that we split your names up into seperate records using a space as a delimiter. `split_to_table` will generate a new record for each token encountered.

We can also capture a `row_number()` for each `firstname` so we can stitch the records back together using `string_agg` after using `substring()` to get the intitial.

```
SELECT  
  string_agg(initial, '') as initials
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY firstname) as recnum,
      substring(regexp_split_to_table(t.firstname, '\s+') FROM 1 FOR 1) as initial 
    FROM test as t
  ) t_init
GROUP BY recnum
```

You can check out a working example at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/299fd/12)

The cool thing about using this method is that the firstname can be a single word, or 100 words. A name like "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt" will turn into "JJJS" just as easily as the name "Harold" will turn into "H", all within the same query.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with an upper limit of names in the column, something like this might be cheaper:

```
select given_names, (string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[1],
       concat( 
              left((string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[1], 1),
              left((string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[2], 1),
              left((string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[3], 1),
              left((string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[4], 1),
              left((string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[5], 1),
              left((string_to_array(given_names, ' '))[6], 1)
             )
from borrower;
```

This will return the initials for the first 6 names (where a "name" is anything between spaces). If you also need to take other whitespace (tabs, newlines) into account you can use: `regexp_split_to_array(given_names, '\s')` instead of `string_to_array()`.

The above "works" as long as you can impose a practical limit on the number of names in the column. I would probably put that into a view, so it can be changed easily in a single place if you need to increase the maximum number of names

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution using *regex*

```
SELECT string_agg(arr [1], '') AS initials
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn
        ,regexp_matches(fname, '\y(?!(the|of)\y)\w', 'gi') arr
    FROM tblnames
    ) t
GROUP BY rn
```

[**SQL Fiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a684e/2)

---

Solution 1

```
SELECT string_agg(col, '') initials
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn
        ,left(unnest(string_to_array(fname, ' ')), 1) col
    FROM tblnames
    ) t
GROUP BY rn
```

---

Solution 2

With following table as example

```
CREATE TABLE tblnames
(
    fname varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO tblnames VALUES 
  ('Stack Overflow'),
  ('Stack Over Flow'),
  ('Stackoverflow');
```

running this select statement

```
select string_agg(col,'') from (
SELECT left(unnest(string_to_array('Stack Over Flow', ' ')),1) col
)t
```

gives out put as

```
string_agg
text
---------
SOF
```

So we can wrap the above select statement into a function like below

```
create or replace function getInitials(col text) returns text 
As
$$
SELECT string_agg(col, '')
FROM (
    SELECT left(unnest(string_to_array(col, ' ')), 1) col
    ) t

$$
language sql
```

So that we can get initial letter of each *fname* in table *tblnames* like following select

```
select fname,getInitials(fname)  initails from  tblnames
```

---