# Selecting first letter of each word in a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column where I need to select the first letter of each word using SQL, with the output looking like the following

Table Name: Data

```
|  COLUMN  | OUTPUT | 
_____________________
| John Doe |   JD   |
| Bob Dole |   BD   |
| Dan Roby |   DR   |
_____________________
```

Choosing Left or Right via SQL would only select a specific letter based on length of strong, so unsure how to approach this

Any suggestions would be appreciated, previous examples in comments below don't work for Azure SQL Server given "regexp_split_to_table" isn't recognized and explicit case statements won't work for this example.

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190028/first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First letter of each word in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190028/first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-column)

Comment: Remember this is a SQL Server question, postgres answers aren't duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string into words in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696106/split-string-into-words-in-columns)

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: None of those examples work - functions like regexp_split_to_table aren't recognized in Azure SQL Server nor does building a lengthy case statement scale for the type of data I'm dealing with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution. It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (col) VALUES
(N'John Doe'),
(N'Bob Dole'),
(N'Dan Roby'),
(N'Mary Smith Robert Polack');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *,
     (SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(value,1), '')
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(col, SPACE(1))
            ) AS Result
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------+--------+
| ID |           col            | Result |
+----+--------------------------+--------+
|  1 | John Doe                 | JD     |
|  2 | Bob Dole                 | BD     |
|  3 | Dan Roby                 | DR     |
|  4 | Mary Smith Robert Polack | MSRP   |
+----+--------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I added to my answer one additional row with four words. The same `SELECT ...` statement outputs correct result.

Comment: @ YitzhakKhabinsky . . . I misread the code.  It is not guaranteed to return the initials in any particular order.  You have no `ORDER BY` clause on `STRING_AGG()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string_split()` and then bring them back together:

```
select t.*, x.inits
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(left(s.value, 1), '') within group (order by ind) as inits
      from (select s.*, charindex(' ' + s.value + ' ', ' ' + t.name + ' ') as ind
            from string_split(t.name, ' ') s
           ) s
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=356e6cf801ff9888c7b124ac3b45d483) is a db<>fiddle.

Aaron Bertrand insists that the more recent versions of SQL Server keep results of `string_split()` in order.  However, until this is represented in the documentation, I would be hesitant to use it.

Comment: What does within group do here ?

Comment: @Manakin . . . It keeps the initials in the order they should be in.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff thanks !  My SQL skills are pretty trash so I follow this tag to aide my learning I couldn't equate the docs to within group to what it was used for here