# SQL code to get the first letter of two strings

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the first letter of a single name and full name.
For example

```
Name

Alex Patterson
Alex
```

Output should be

```
A P
A
```

Can someone help me with to achieve this?

Comment: sql server or mysql or oracle? Depending on the database used you can actually use string functions to get the first letter from each word

Comment: Please specify the DBMS you're using.

Comment: You could add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Jonathan Rhys-Davies and Carl van der Walt to the sample data, and also adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: I am writing using Snow Sql. The challenge I face is to get the first letter of the second string with the space.  So here A P

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/charindex.html   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/substr.html https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/left.html

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I saw this but what if the length of the strings is different ? I mean a column has 10 entries and each name has different length obviously. So getting first of letter of first string is fine. How about the first letter of 2nd string?

Comment: CHARINDEX on the separating character?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767386/selecting-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

For recent SQL Server:

```
SELECT Name, STRING_AGG (initial, ' ') as full_initial
FROM (
SELECT Name, SUBSTRING(value,1,1) as initial
FROM people
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(name, ' ')
) t
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).